# Visibility assertion difference

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to assert on the visibility of the two elements (id1 and id2), which are stacked above each other.

```
<div id="main" style="left: 99px; top: 1306px; visibility: visible;">
        <div id="id1"  style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 35px; visibility: hidden;"></div><!--ImageBckgrMappingSlotSelected3-->
        <div id="id2" style="left: 1px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 35px; visibility: visible;"></div><!--ImageBckgrMappingSlotSelecable3-->
```

with the command:

```
cy.get('#id2').should('be.visible')
```

The assertion fails and shows the error that it is hidden by the element with #id1. But when i use:

```
cy.get('#id2').should('have.attr','style','left: 1px; top: 0px; width: 400px; height: 35px; visibility: visible;')
```

the assertion succeeds. Why does the first one fail?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the error exactly gives you the reason why it is failing. You can either go for the assertion that you have chosen in the second point or you can also use `expect($el).to.be.hidden`. Both will ultimately check that the element is present in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i can only check the visibility with `.should('be.visible')` if the element is not covered? What is the benefit of that method?

Comment: The method can be used for an assertion. For example if a part of the page is rendering after a form commit - you can check if the result is visible after the render.

Comment: Alapan Das why do you think the method `expect($el).to.be.hidden` to be viable for him? In my expirience it will not be viable for covered elements that are visible to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

In my expirience `.should('be.visible')` checks for phisical visibility and `.should('have.attr', 'someAttribute')` - only checks if the element has the attribute.

According to [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Notes) -  `.should()` command only checks what you order it to check and nothing else, inculidng if the element exists.

Comment: I don‘t have problems to check the visibility, just wanted to understand why it fails. Thank you though.

Comment: I understamd it that the should(be.visible) checks phsysical visibility, while the other - the attribute